# Top bar on SE sites... changed [again] recently?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

Am I going mad? Is this a recent change or have I simply never noticed it before?

When you scroll any SE page, the top bar, search etc stays in place [wasting screen space]. If I need to look at the top bar, I know exactly where it is & can get there with a single click/keystroke. I don't need it following me down the page like a lost puppy.

[image]

Comment: I sort of like the search bar following me. Sorry.

Comment: No need to be sorry ;) Any pref that doesn't have an off-switch is a 'bad move' in my book... now we found the off-switch, we can all have it whichever way we prefer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can disable the stickyness via your [settings](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) under 'Preferences':

[image]

Comment: Is it new, or did a pref flip without me asking it to?

Comment: Eh ... I don't know. I got it from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312501/2952320).

Comment: That would seem to imply it went live only yesterday [when I was out all day] so at least goes some way to disproving my 'madness theory' ;) I also note the hideous new sidebar is to get an off-switch too. Sanity may still be preserved, after all.